# Trying add new Vhost in Xampp but its redirecting to Xampp own page

Tags: apache, xampp, vhosts

I have my website in `HTDOCS` folder of `Xampp` so for this I tried to update the host file in `windows/system32/etc/host`. It looks like this

```
# localhost name resolution is handled within DNS itself.
#   127.0.0.1       localhost
#   ::1             localhost

127.0.0.1       localhost
127.0.0.1       idecon2.0.test
```

And My vhost-httpd.conf file looks like this

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot "C:/xampp/htdocs/idecon2.0/public"
    ServerName idecon2.0.test
</VirtualHost>
```

but when I write idecon2.0.test in my browser it redirects to the xampp home page.

Am I missing something here

Please advise